# Are these two vectors parallel?

Tags: vectors

Let there be a vector **x** and **v** and scalar k. **x** and **v** are parallel if **x**=k**v**.

If **x** = (4, -1) and **v** = ( -8 , 2 ) these are parallel.

If **u** = (4, -1) and **z** = ( 8 , 2 ) is **u** and **z** parallel?

Comment: No because there's no number $k$ such that $(4,-1) = k(8,2)$.  If there were then you'd be able to solve $4=8k$ and $-1 = 2k$ **for the same $k$**.

Comment: You never use $\mathbf z$ in your question, so you probably have a typo.